# How to close a native select element within a modal dialog with Escape without closing the modal?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, accessibility, html-select

I have a vanilla HTML modal created using a generic divisor with `role=dialog`. I would like to close the modal on Escape.

However, the modal itself also includes a native `<select>` element whose options list can be closed with Escape. With the enclosed code added, pressing Escape while the `<select>` element is open will also close the modal.

How to only close the `<select>` element on Escape, and leave the modal dialog open?

```
window.onkeyup = (event) => {
  if (modal.style.display === "block") {
    if (event.code === "Escape") {
      modal.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a [very minimal example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nogcb8tu/) to demonstrate the issue. Try opening the "modal", then opening up the `<select>` element (with Space, Alt + Down, a click or tap, or what have you), and then pressing the Escape key while the `<select>` options list is still open to see what my question is about.

Observed on Firefox 106.0.5 on Ubuntu (Gnome, X11).

Comment: Please, could you tell with which browser you have observed that behavior at least ?  And if possible, provide an example page so that we can test easily in several browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial workaround, you can add a `stopPropagation` call added onto the `<select>` element to partially work around the issue as shown in another  [minimal example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd7uhqbx/). The fiddle also includes `tabindex=0` within the modal dialog container to demonstrate that the Escape handler correctly works while the `<select>` element is not in focus.

This will cause the `<select>` element to no longer incorrectly close the modal dialog if Escape is pressed while the options list is open; however, the modal dialog will not close on Escape while the `<select>` element is in focus, even if the options list is not open.